# Why am i getting runtime error while executing the following code for Codeforces 231 A?

Tags: python, loops

This is the [question](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/231/A):

> One day three best friends Petya, Vasya and Tonya decided to form a team and take part in programming contests. Participants are usually
> offered several problems during programming contests. Long before the
> start the friends decided that they will implement a problem if at
> least two of them are sure about the solution. Otherwise, the friends
> won't write the problem's solution.
>
> This contest offers n problems to the participants. For each problem
> we know, which friend is sure about the solution. Help the friends
> find the number of problems for which they will write a solution.
>
> Input The first input line contains a single integer n (1 ≤ n ≤ 1000)
> — the number of problems in the contest. Then n lines contain three
> integers each, each integer is either 0 or 1. If the first number in
> the line equals 1, then Petya is sure about the problem's solution,
> otherwise he isn't sure. The second number shows Vasya's view on the
> solution, the third number shows Tonya's view. The numbers on the
> lines are separated by spaces.
>
> Output Print a single integer — the number of problems the friends
> will implement on the contest.

This is the code that I wrote for this:

```
n=input()
a=0
for i in range (0,n):
    l,m,o= int(input().split())
    if l+m+o>1:
        a+=1
    else:
        a+=0
print (a)
```

But it always shows runtime error. I am unable to figure out what exactly is wrong here. I thought it was a global-local variable problem but  apparently its not. I also tried taking inputs in the form of a list and then summing up integers but that didnt work either.

PS This is my first question here so I apologize in advance for silly errors.

Comment: `input().split()` is a list not an int.  Try `l,m,o = map(int, input().split())`.  Also you need: `n=int(input())`

Comment: @DarrylG still showing runtime error. It is showing a=0 as output idk why.